# Where does Tor save logs when run from browser bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, log

I want to read Tor logs when running Tor from Browser Bundle (on Linux).

[In official FAQ, I read:](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#Logs)

> You'll have to go find the log files by hand. Here are some likely
>   places for your logs to be:
>
> - On OS X, Debian, Red Hat, etc, the logs are in `/var/log/tor/`
> - On Windows, there are no default log files currently. If you enable logs in your torrc file, they default to `\username\Application
>     Data\tor\log\` or `\Application Data\tor\log\`
> - If you compiled Tor from source, by default your Tor logs to "stdout" at log-level notice. If you enable logs in your torrc file,
>     they default to `/usr/local/var/log/tor/`.

However, that makes no sense. I am runing the bundle as a non-root user, it cannot write into `/var/log/tor` or `/usr/local/var/log/tor`.

I have looked into all the sub-folders in the bundle and I don't see a thing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor Browser does not keep an on-disk log by default. Instead, you can get the log from the Browser. Click on the green onion, Tor Network Settings, and then on the bottom there's a button to copy the log to your clipboard.